# React Update form with Success or Error message on submit

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to find a way on how to display a message after the submit - return a thank you message if everything is ok, or error if something went wrong. How do I change this component in order to make it work?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from "./styles.module.less";
import arrow from "./../../images/whiteArrow.png"
class Subscribe extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Subscribe}>
         <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <h1>Don't miss out on the latest</h1>
            <form className={styles.email}>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email-inp" spellCheck="false" required />
              <label for="text" className={styles.labelClass}>
                <span className={styles.spanClass}>
                Enter your email address
                </span>
              </label>
              <button type="submit"><img className={styles.arrow} src={arrow}/></button>

            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Subscribe;
```

Comment: when u click on the button, the page would reload because of a form submit. There is nothing you can do on client to find if the request was successful or not. From the server you can redirect with an appropriate `urlParam` and use it on `render` to show/hide` respective message